# Manhwa/Manhua/… Where a concubine sees the emperor get killed

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

The female gets married to the emperor (one who has a lot of concubines and all). On the first night, to consummate the marriage, the prince (maybe a blonde crown prince) enter the room by a secret passage and kill his father the emperor in front of the concubine. After that, in other to survive, she was supposed to choose between the prince or the empress (or dowager) since the empress wants to kill the prince.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: @DavidW hi it was a long time ago maybe more than 2 years or maybe 3 and it was on a website like topmanhua.com, manhwatop.com, bato where you can find a lot of stories.

Answer (score 2):

This is *[Empress of Another World](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/empress-of-another-world)*. It is licensed by [Tappytoon](https://www.tappytoon.com/en/book/empressoaw).

> Crossing over into another world and time after a freak accident, Korean highschool girl Sabina is taken in by a duke of the Crentia kingdom— only to soon be **offered up to the ugly old emperor as a concubine. When the king is killed by a mysterious assassin**, Sabina must face the poisonous circle of other candidates in a battle for the royal seat. Can she attract the loyalty and affection of the men and women she needs on her side to survive?

Synopsis covers much of it: girl is married to the emperor, but he's killed by his son right before consummating the marriage.

[image: Assassin]

The emperor has an empress and many concubines,

[image: Empress and the other concubines]